# iTextPdf how to break page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I generate pdf file from html page using iTextPdf like:

```
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(HTML);
            hw.Parse(reader);
            document.Close();
```

but my html page is large and I need to add page brakes in specific places.

How can I add these page breaks in pdf?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `HTMLWorker.ParseToList`. Can't you use that?

1. Get n elements from ParseToList
2. Add first x elements to PDF
3. Call NewPage on PDF
4. Add remaining elements to PDF

Comment: Yes, it resolved my problem, you can also read for example here: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/itextsharp-question-pagebreak-91962.aspx

Comment: The sample is accessible through archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20121228001356/http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/itextsharp-question-pagebreak-91962.aspx

Answer (score 13):

**Since, iTextSharp do have limitations in understanding few HTML styles/tags.**

**The solution to this is a little workaround:**

- You need to create a new class which extends the `HTMLWorker` class
         and overrides the `StartElement` method which gives us event on
         starting of every html element.

  ```
  public class HTMLWorkerExtended : HTMLWorker
  {
  public HTMLWorkerExtended(IDocListener document): base(document)
  {

  }
  public override void StartElement(string tag, IDictionary<string, string> str)
  {
      if (tag.Equals("newpage"))
          document.Add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
      else
          base.StartElement(tag, str);
  }
  }
  ```
- In your html, add `<newpage />` tag wherever you want a page break.
- Now use `HTMLWorkerExtended` class' object to parse the html.

  ```
  using (TextReader htmlViewReader = new StringReader(htmlText))
   {
      using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorkerExtended(pdfDocument))
        {
           htmlWorker.Open();
           htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
        }
   }
  ```

Comment: seems to be working, but always  adding new page in the first page not in appropriate position

Comment: Works like a charm when using CKEditor builtin Page Breaks (CSS property style="page-break-after : always"

Answer (score 6):

try adding the following in your HTML:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: You might want to try using ABCPdf.  It works great, but not free!

Comment: See answer by T Gupta above. I used his approach to parse CKEditor builtin "page-break" feature and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code when you want to insert page break:

document.NewPage();

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

I have tried this and it works:

```
<div style="page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</div>
```